# Which Python Code is better to use? Or for this does it not matter as much

Tags: python, python-3.x

Option 1:

```
numbers = [5, 2, 5, 2, 2]
chances = 0                 
while chances < 5:          
    for x in numbers:        
        print('*' * x)       
        chances +=1
```

Or option 2:

```
numbers = [5, 2, 5, 2, 2]
for x in numbers:
    output = ''   
    for count in range(x): 
        output += 'x'     
    print(output)
```

Just curious because I like the implementation of option 1 better, I seem to grasp that more.

Comment: Which one do you think is more likely to break in case `numbers` change?

Comment: all you need is: `for x in numbers: print('*' * x)` The `while` loop does nothing in the first example.

Answer (score 1):

There isn’t much difference, the logic is if you have iterable data structures you can for ‘for ’, as it much easier else if it is simple condition you can go for ‘while’. In first option , at some time in the future you have to change to ‘while chances < len(numbers)’ which means already along with wasteful variable ‘chances’, you are again calling number array. So I would defintely recommend option 2.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be:

```
numbers = [5, 2, 5, 2, 2]
for x in numbers:
    print("x" * x)
```

You don't need the while loop at all in the first example.

Answer (score -4):

You can also write it in one line:

```
    [print('*'*x) for x in [5, 2, 5, 2, 2]]
```

or to have the numbers as a variable:

```
    numbers = [5, 2, 5, 2, 2]
    [print('*'*x) for x in numbers]
```

But this will create a list of None elements with the length of the original list. In this case 
`[None, None, None, None, None]`

As suggested in the comment below a better solution would be:

`print('\n'.join('*' * x for x in numbers))`

Comment: No, this is bad. Don't use list comprehensions for side effects. You needlessly create the list `[None, None, None, None, None]` when you do that. If you want to print as a one-liner, make a string: `print('\n'.join('*' * x for x in numbers))`

Comment: @MarkMeyer - Thanks for the input, did not think about the negative aspects of creating a list. I fixed my answer.